# Populate other email fields like Subject in Python mail function

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I have tested this piece of code and it sends the email successfully, it tends to leave the subject fields, cc and bcc fields empty as seen in the photo.

```
import smtplib

gmail_user = 'dummy@gmail.com'  
gmail_password = 'password'



sent_from = 'dummy@gmail.com'  
to = ['receiver@gmail.com']  
subject = 'OMG Super Important Message'  
body = "Hey, what's up?\n\n- You"

email_text = """\
From: %s  
To: %s  
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

try:  
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    print("establish connection successful")
    server.ehlo()
    print("identification successful")
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    print("login successful")
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    print("send mail successful")
    server.close()
    print('Email sent!')
except:  
    print('Something went wrong...')
```

Does anyone know how I can fill them up through this script?

[image: Screenshot of received mail]

Comment: Replace `subject = 'OMG Super Important Message'  ` whth `subject = "OMG Super Important Message"  ` - Try that

Comment: Brought image inline and modified the title to better reflect the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the email subject - there is a specific format to the input arg you provide to server.sendmail that should work. Could you try:

```
subject = 'This is the email subject'
text = 'This is the email body'
message = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, text)
server.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to open the source of an email you will see something like this:

```
   Received: from ************.net ([***.**.2.17]) by
   *****.****.net ([**.***.224.162]) with mapi id **.03.****.***;
   Mon, 22 May 2017 09:14:59 +0200
   From: *FROMEMAIL* <******@***.com>
   To: *TOEMAIL* <********@***.com>
   CC: *CCEMAIL* <********@*****.com>
   Subject: E-mail - 150633**0686_****.pdf
   ...
```

That is the header of the email, so if you try something like this:

```
import smtplib

gmail_user = 'dummy@gmail.com'  
gmail_password = 'password'



sent_from = 'dummy@gmail.com'  
to = ['receiver@gmail.com']  
subject = 'OMG Super Important Message'  
body = "Hey, what's up?\n\n- You"
cc = "****@***.com"
bcc = "******@*****.com"
email_text = """\
From: %s  
To: %s
CC: %s
BCC: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), cc, bcc,subject, body)

try:  
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    print("establish connection successful")
    server.ehlo()
    print("identification successful")
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    print("login successful")
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    print("send mail successful")
    server.close()
    print('Email sent!')
except:  
    print('Something went wrong...')
```

I think it will work